# Subfolders under Queries in SQL Server 2008 Solution

Tags: sql-server-2008

Can you add subfolders under Queries in  SQL Server 2008 Solution? There are large number of query files and it is getting unmanageable.

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work. The project system is a very underused feature of SQL Server - unfortunately, compared to "real" Visual Studio, it's also rather crippled :-(

I even tried "tricking" it into using subfolders by manually editing the (XML based) `*.ssmssqlproj` project file (**what a file extension!!**), but even this wasn't successful - the queries where still all presented in a single list :-(

Marc